# How to convert your curl command to equivalent Python requests code

Tags: python, python-requests

I was trying to convert the curl command to a Python post request, but I was not able to.

```bash
curl -k -u admin:admin -X POST --header "Content-Type:multipart/mixed"--header "Accept:application/json"-F "myPartnm1=@sftprest;type=application/json"-F" myPartname2=@sftppvteopenkey;type=application/json/oc-stream" http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert
```

```py
If response.status_code==200 :
Print (response.text)
```

Comment: For one thing that's **not** Python, which is case sensitive and whose whitespace has meaning. For another you're showing nothing of how the request is _sent_, only what you try to do with the response.

Comment: Try using https://curlconverter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [curlconverter.com](https://curlconverter.com/) you get this:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed--header',
}

response = requests.post('http://cdrteo456.serms.com:4456/api/v/cert', headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('admin', 'admin'))
```

Comment: hi im facing some error saying utf coded cant decode byte 0xa8 in position  0